# Angular @if vs ngIf, are they different?

Tags: angular

Is there any benefit of using the new `@if` instead of the classic `ngIf` directive?

`*ngIf` version:

```js
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'scrollbars',
  imports: [NgIf, ScrollbarX, ScrollbarY],
  template: `
    <scrollbar-x *ngIf="horizontalUsed()"/>
    <scrollbar-y *ngIf="verticalUsed()"/>
  `
})
```

`@if` version:

```js
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'scrollbars',
  imports: [ScrollbarX, ScrollbarY],
  template: `
    @if (verticalUsed()) {
      <scrollbar-y/>
    }
    @if (horizontalUsed()) {
      <scrollbar-x/>
    }
  `
})
```

Besides the syntax difference, I noticed that I don't need to import `NgIf` or `CommonModule` to make `@if` work, which is nice!

I would appreciate if someone can explain if it works differently behind the scene

Comment: they are slightly different, as under the hood they are using slightly different apis, but I doubt it is possible to find differencce in behavior. We can safely assume there is no difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functionnaly speaking yes, An `@if` block replaces the usage of the `ngIf` directive.

However, there are some technical advantages to use the new control flow blocks (`@for/@if/@switch`).

1. You don't need to import the directive or the `CommonModule` when build standalone components.
2. Droping thoses directives also drops a few kBs from the main bundle.
3. Expect some perf improvements (due to less template instructions needed), some details in [this article](https://angularindepth.com/posts/1525/diving-into-the-new-angular-control-flow-internals)

Answer (score 0):

The `@if` block replaces `*ngIf` for expressing conditional parts of the UI.
It also supports referencing of expression results to keep a solution for common coding patterns

> `@if (users$ | async; as users) {   {{ users.length }} }`

There is no significant difference from *ngIf as its also removing the HTML element from the DOM.